# Daemon OpenVPN configuration file with .conf?

Tags: ssh, openvpn

In the video, there is one machine connected to another via SSH, where the second OpenVPN daemon is already started and configured with a user/password requested at login:

http://youtu.be/tSNCE6j2zxM

How do I configure the OpenVPN daemon to get it started and configured with user/password automatically? What are the directories to move? What commands do I need?

Comment: In case the video goes missing. A user logs in to a terminal and then is instantly prompted to log into another machine.

Comment: Since this appears to be related to another question you asked about logins, does this happen on all of the machines you log in to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a simple login script that immediately connects to another box. Something like:

```
~$ cat .bash_profile
clear
telnet <the-other-box>
```

Not sure why you mention OpenVPN. It doesn't look like OpenVPN is involved here...